# SQL Query to get the last entry in a year and handle ties

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to get only those records that are latest in each year from the following sample data, in case of tie get the one with highest ObjectID. (please see the image and SQL fiddle). Any help is appreciated. 
(DB: SQL Server 2008)

please see the SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ce73/1

I want all the records that gets latest entry in each year and in case of tie get the one that has highest ObjectID.

Image Input Data and Results expected:

[image: Input Data and Results expected]

I was trying the sample code but no avail:

```
SELECT t1.*, Year(lastvaluationdate) as Val_year FROM FS t1
WHERE t1.objectid = (SELECT MAX(t2.objectid)
                 FROM FS t2              
                 WHERE t2.ENTITYUID = t1.ENTITYUID and t2.LASTVALUATIONDATE 
                 = t1.LASTVALUATIONDATE)                    
order by ENTITYUID
```

Comment: The results don't match the what you asked. For example, EntityUID `1GCPCPEA3AZ122834` has records from both 2017 and 2016, but only the 2017 shows in your result set.

Comment: Also, we **MUCH** prefer text in your question. For one thing, it would make it possible for us to fix that error in the sample results for you. We consider it very rude to post images of your data or results.

Comment: @Joel Coehoom, At the outset, thanks for your time and help. This works. My Apologies, I see what your saying, image is will not help here. Although my intention was clearly to help make it easier to understand. good lesson for me in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EntityUID, YEAR(LastValuationDate) YR FROM FS) t0
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM FS t1 
    WHERE t1.EntityUID = t0.EntityUID AND YEAR(t1.LastValuationDate) = t0.YR
    ORDER BY t1.LastValuationDate DESC, t1.ObjectID DESC
) t2
ORDER BY EntityUID DESC, LastValuationDate DESC, ObjectID DESC
```

> [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ce73/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using window functions for this:

```
SELECT FS.*
FROM (SELECT FS.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  EntityUID, Year(lastvaluationdate)
                                ORDER BY lastvaluationdate DESC, ObjectId DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM FS
     ) FS
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, Although it seems working but there is something wrong. out of 200 records, it returns only 21. It doesn't take care of those records that only has single entry that is only one record in a year!. One more thing, compare the SQL Fiddle with image i attached. there is atleast 5 records needed as result but your's only bring 3. I think we are close only to be grouped by year. "Your query bring latest entry in Entity's life but we want each entry per year."

Comment: @Abdul I fixed it. You never said in the question you wanted to also separate by EntityUID. We kinda had to infer that, and it's not easy to read in the image you posted (hint: text is always better here).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks, this works like Charm. Yes, as I read the question again, I missed explaining about the EntitiyUID. It was in my head but missed in writing. Thanks for pointing

Comment: @Gordon my apologies to you, the question with missing point, may have giving you hard time. Thanks for your help!